# Enable and disable textbox through button?(asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT0cd.png)My tutor gave me the following task: Create a form with 3 buttons(Save(Guardar) Edit(Editar) Delete(Eliminar) ).

But my real question is this:

I need to link my text box to my button allowing me to disable it and enable it at will but I can't conect them trough code.

PS:If you answer this question try as much as you can to be specific about the terms you use since I've started learning asp.net a few days ago.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chmvi.png)

Comment: This site isn't here to do your assignments for you. Put in some effort first, show your code and what isn't working, if anything and then post here.

Comment: I actualy did an link is attached to the comment so people can see what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the button event.
Double click to the button on your form, then the VB will create a button event automatically.
Now, you can code.
For i.e:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = false;//Disable textbox1 on the form
    }
```

Comment: I already did that but when I run the form the button dosen't allow the enable instruction to be true and it stay's false

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RedioButton.aspx.cs" Inherits="Shoping_Cart.RedioButton" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Enable Disable Textbox Using Jascript Radio Button Click</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function EnableDisableTextBox() {
            var status = document.getElementById('<%=rbtEnable.ClientID %>').checked;
            if (status == true) {
                document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="228px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtEnable" runat="server" Text="Enable" onclick="javascript:EnableDisableTextBox();" GroupName="1" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtDisable" runat="server" Text="Disable" onclick="javascript:EnableDisableTextBox();" GroupName="1" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?